# Retrospectively applying an .hgignore file to a Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Is it possible to stop tracking a bunch of files in a repo by somehow retrospectively applying an `.hgignore` file?

I am aware that a file that is already tracked, will continue to be so even if you add a rule to an `.hgignore` file that matches it

Is there a workaround to this?

In other words, I want to add an `.hgignore` file to my repo then somehow get the repo to stop tracking all files that match the `.hgignore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do so.

You can `hg forget PATTERN` several files at once. Check `hg help fileset` and `hg help patterns` on how to efficiently specify several files.

If you want to forget all files which are ignored, you could try what is one example in the output of `hg help fileset`:

```
hg forget "set:hgignore() and not ignored()"
```

EDIT: If you want to do the same thing also to the history of the repository, you can use `hg convert` and exclude certain file patterns to be included in the new, converted repository.

Comment: possibly add the .hgignore then hg addremove?

Comment: `hg addremove` will not help; it will not forget or remove files which are already tracked but in the ignore pattern. It will forget files which are removed and add files which are found and don't match any ignore pattern.

Comment: Personally I do not like `hg addremove` one bit as it results in the problem you describe in this question. I nearly always have some files which I don't want to track but which are not in my ignore pattern.

Comment: @planetmaker: how exactly do you specify patterns in map file when using `hg convert --filemap map.txt`? I'm trying to exclude all files of `*.type`, but the converted repo still contains them..

Comment: If you want to exclude files ending with `.type` on all levels of your dir tree, use `**.type`.